# Pandas filter DataFrame based on row , column and date

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, selenium, pandas-groupby

Everyone. 
I am trying to filter data based on row name , column and date based.
I have data as you can see in image below, I am scraping html table using selenium.

Data I have

[image]

complete code :

```
https://repl.it/@AshfaqueMarfani/DroopyDismalCubase
```

I want to filter data like this.

```
argument : date 2018-11-10 to 2018-12-1
2018-11-10 | Total Issues Traded | 8243
2018-11-11 | Total Issues Traded | 8232
2018-11-12 | Total Issues Traded | 90000
2018-11-13 | Total Issues Traded | 10000
2018-11-14 | Total Issues Traded | 8243
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood your question correctly, you want to filter by date and by value of the first column in your dataframe. One of the ways to achieve it is the following:

```
df[df['date'].between('2018-11-10', '2018-12-01')&(df[0]=='Total Issues Traded')]
```

Comment: Thankyou so much for your answer.
You did great.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df[(df.0 == "Total Issues Traded")]
```

OR

```
df.loc[df['0'] == "Total Issues Traded"]
```

OR

```
df.loc[df['0'] == "Total Issues Traded" & df['date'] > '2018-11-09') & (df['date'] < '2018-12-02')]
```

Let me know if this is what you want or you need some changes

Comment: I want to use date + row name and column

Comment: you want filter the data based on some dates also..as mentioned

Comment: I think above answer might work, Thankyou for your precious time bro.